# New-PSSession cannot connect

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell so if I overlooked something please let me know. I am trying to connect to a computer using PSSession. I use the following `$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "ip address or host name here" -Credential $cred -Authentication Default`. When I use a host name I get the following error.

```
Connecting to remote server "hostname here" failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because
 | the server name cannot be resolved. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

When I try with an IP address I get this error instead.

```
Connecting to remote server "ip address here" failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is
 | accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to
 | remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I have set the trusted hosts with `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts *`. When I run `WINRM quickconfig` I get the following message.

```
Message = WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.
```

My network connection type is set to Domain so I am unsure what is going on here. The only thing I could think of is someone had a similar error that they resolve by temporarily disabling adapters which had been created by virtualization software and I am pretty sure I don't have any virtualization software. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong let me know thanks.

Comment: have you set it on the remote machine as well? Beside being on a domain, your connection has to be set to private if on a workgroup. Otherwise, `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` should set everything for you to be able to connect; you just have to run it on both sides.

Comment: The first error message is telling you that the DNS for "hostname" could not be resolved. You may need to use the fully qualified domain name "hostname.example.com" or a similar "hostname.local" format.

Answer (score 0):

WinRM is required for PowerShell remoting. WinRM is Microsoft's implementation of a standard called WSMan. WSMan is an open standard created with many other large tech companies (Dell, Intel, etc.). To test whether or not this is functioning, you can use the following cmdlet.

```
Test-WSMAN -ComputerName $Computer -Authentication default
```

As previous response indicates, it is likely that this is not properly configured. The `Enable-PSRemoting` command should guide you through this process. Literature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.2).

You'll also want to verify the WinRM service is running on both hosts. If it is not running, start it and try again. You can do this remotely.

```
Get-Service -Name WinRM -ComputerName $computer
Get-Service -Name WinRM -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
```